# $R$-orientation of a manifold

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $M$ be an $n$ dimensional manifold and $R$ be a commutative ring. $\Gamma_c(S;R)$ denotes the space of sections onto the orientation bundle with compact support. 
For any closed set $K$, $H_n(M,M\backslash K;R)\cong \Gamma_c(K;R)$. Now, let us assume $K$ is compact and connected. If we consider the right-hand side there is no way to restrict us (at least I don't see) to take a constant section valued any element in $R$. So $\Gamma_c(K;R)\cong R$ (no matter the orientability of $K$). But on the other hand, there is also a fact: if $M$ is non-orientable along $K$ then $H_n(M,M\backslash K;R)\cong \{r\in R| r=-r\} $. Is this a contradiction?

And another question is is there any difference (or significance) to take consider an arbitrary coefficient ring in comparison to $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Is $M$ a manifold? What's $n$? What does $\Gamma_c$ denote? Is $R$ supposed to be any ring, or do you mean $\Bbb R$? And from where do you get the isomorphism of your first sentence, which looks as if it might be true only if $M$ is $R$-orientable?

Comment: @JohnHughes I just updated the conditions. I don't think $M$ need to be $R$-orientable.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier I think I still described it wrongly, the condition is call "$M$ is not orientable along $K$". Yes, if $K$ is a point, then $M$ is orientable along $K$.

Answer (score 1):

> If we consider the right-hand side there is no way to restrict us (at least I don't see) to take a constant section valued any element in $R$.

This assumes that the orientation bundle actually **has** nonzero-everywhere sections. In the case where $M$ is the Mobius strip (or $\Bbb RP^2$) this assumption is false: the orientation bundle is twisted, and it doesn't even make sense to talk about a "constant section" (as it would if the orientation bundle were just $M \times R$). Which is why, taking $M = \Bbb R P ^2$ and $K = M$, we get
$$
H_n(M, \emptyset; \Bbb Z) = 0
$$
which makes sense, because $\Gamma(M;R) = 0$. (Note that "compact support" here is irrelevant, because $M$ is a compact manifold to start with.)

Comment: Thanks, now for me the problem now is what is the topology defined on the orientation bundle? $O(M;R)=\sqcup_{x\in M} {H_n(M,M\backslash\{x\};R)}$. $R$ is discrete so I have the feeling that it must be $M\times R$. And this is for sure a bundle because it is trivial (globally).

Comment: Well...for the Mobius strip, for instance, you have $x \times \Bbb Z$ at each point $x$, but the "gluing" between the fibers at $x = 0$ and $x = 1$ is the homomorphism $u \mapsto -u$ on $\Bbb Z$.